# Copy All Files and Subfolders from Directory A to Director B on Start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, copy, subdirectory

I'm trying to copy an entire directory (including all files and subfolders) from one destination to another on game launch. I've looked at scripts mentioned previously here: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1157689/copy-an-entire-directory-to-another-folder-through.html

However, this doesn't seem to copy subfolders and subfolder contents - any suggestions would be really helpful!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceDirectory = @"C:\temp\source";
        string targetDirectory = @"C:\temp\destination";

        Copy(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory);

        Console.WriteLine("\r\nEnd of program");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Copy(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
    {
        var diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
        var diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

        CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
    }

    public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);

        // Copy each file into the new directory.
        foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", target.FullName, fi.Name);
            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
        }

        // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
                target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
            CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unity does not use `static void Main`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursion. Basically you have a method for copying a folder and the content to somewhere. If that folder contains any subfolders, run the same method for each subfolder, which will then do the same.

Example:

```
static void CopyFolder(string path, string target)
{
    // Create target directory
    Directory.CreateDirectory(target);

    // Copy all files
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(target, Path.GetFileName(file)));

    // Recursively copy all subdirectories
    foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        CopyFolder(directory, Path.Combine(target, Path.GetFileName(directory)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In that code it only goes through all the files in that folder. You can follow the same concept for all the directories and their files and their directories.... (*hint recursion*).

Here's how you get files `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and directories `Directory.EnumerateDirectories`.